# nsdata that are return fron NSObject class and used in viewcontroller class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an `NSObject` class that contains 3 methods:

```
-(void)RequestForData
{
    #pragma Mark - ASIHTTPRequest

     NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://srv2.vitaminas.it/pdv"];
     ASIHTTPRequest *request=[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [request setDelegate:self];
     [request startSynchronous];

}
```

## pragma Mark - HTTP Delegate

```
- (NSData*)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];

   return responseData;

}


- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"%@",error);

}
```

I have one view controller class, from `viewDidLoad` method of viewcontroller class  call -`RequestForData`  method of `NSObject`  class,

```
WebServiceMethods *web=[[WebServiceMethods alloc]init];

[web RequestForData];

arr_JsonData=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:web  options:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:Nil];

NSLog(@"%@",arr_JsonData);

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

But I want to use `NSData` that are returned from `NSObject` class (i.e  `return responsedata;` ) into view controller class.

I want that `NSData` into arr_JsonData ( `NSMutuableArray` )

What can I do ?

Comment: its an array of object like 

(

{

keyname=value 
keyname=value
},
{
keyname=value 
keyname=value
}

)

Answer (score 0):

Make `responseData` as class level variable. Do not create local instance of it in `requestFinished` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is callbacks. You should put your `viewController` as a delegate of `WebServiceMethods` ( or using blocks is better) to be informed when the request has finished and the populate your `arr_JsonData`

```
@protocol WebServiceMethodsDelegate

- (void)webServiceMethodsDidFinishWithSucess:(NSString *)response; // give this méthode an appropriate name.
- (void)webServiceMethodsDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
@end


@interface WebServiceMethods : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,weak) id <WebServiceMethodsDelegate> delegate;

@end

@implemntation WebServiceMethods : NSObject


- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
  [self.delegate webServiceMethodsDidFinishWithSucess:responseString];

}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSError *error = [request error];
[self.delegate webServiceMethodsDidFailWithError:error];
}

@end
```

Put your viewController conform to the WebServiceMethodsDelegate protocol.

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController <WebServiceMethodsDelegate>
...
@end
```

and know in your the viewDidLoad of your viewController :

```
WebServiceMethods *web=[[WebServiceMethods alloc]init];
web.delegate = self;

[web RequestForData];
```

Put also the delegate methods in viewController.m

```
- (void)webServiceMethodsDidFinishWithSucess:(NSString *)response {
// here you can parse the response and reload your tableView
.....
[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)webServiceMethodsDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
// handle the errors
}
```

PS : There are many problems with your code :

1. Don't use `ASHTTPRequest`, it's not maintained. You can use `AFNetworking`.[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)
2. Put your WebServiceMethods as a shared instance.

....